# MVC Razor Foreach loop (twice) doesn't work, bracketing error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, foreach, brackets

Given:

```
//A Strongly typed view model where the data is passed in perfectly.  
<table id="dt1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Area)
            </th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Hours)
            </th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Minutes)
            </th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PercentOfTotal)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

@foreach (var current in names)
{
    <tr>
    <td>@current</td>
    </tr>
    //Notice this is the problem area.
    //I have a foreach inside of another one.  Razor seems to think I need another "}"
    //But the compiler tells me I need it at line 1 above
    var stuff = @Model.Where(p => p.Name == current);
        foreach (var item in stuff)
        {
            <tr>
            <td>@item.Area</td>
            <td>@item.Hours</td>
            <td>@item.Minutes</td>
            <td>@item.PercentOfTotal</td>
            </tr>
        }
}
</table>
```

No matter what I try razor doesn't like to foreach loops!  Unless I'm doing something wrong...  If I ignore the designer errors and run it, the runtime tells me I need another "}", unless I'm really tired I just can see where I'm missing a bracket.  There's no compiler errors when I remove the second foreach, but as soon as I add the 2nd one....problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `@` in `@Model...`

```
....
var stuff = Model.Where(p => p.Name == current);
foreach (var item in stuff)
{
  ....
```

[@-Named C# Variables + Nested Blocks Generate Broken Code](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1914) for additional information

Answer (score 1):

Also you can write like this

```
    var stuff = Model.Where(p => p.Name == current);
    @foreach (var item in stuff)
    {
        <tr>
        <td>@item.Area</td>
        <td>@item.Hours</td>
        <td>@item.Minutes</td>
        <td>@item.PercentOfTotal</td>
        </tr>
    }
```

I believe than use

```
    Model.AsNoTracking().Where(p => p.Name == current).ToList()
```

and

```
    @for (int i = 0; i < stuff.Count; i++)
```

much better for Database and EF provide.
Because if you don't want change data, the less connection the better.

p.s. sorry for my English, I am learning it )